# php/Ajax - Best practice for pre-loading images

Tags: php, ajax, json, performance, loading

I have put together a script which is very much like the flickr photostream feature. Two thumbnails next to each other, and when you click the next or prev links the next (or previous) two images slide in. Cool!

Currently when the page loads it loads the two images. The first time nxt / prv is used then the next two images or previous two are loaded via ajax, with the id of the first image being passed in the url and the HTML for the two new images returned and displayed via ajax.

simple enough, but it got me to thinking, on a slow connection, or heavy server load then the two images, although relatively small thumbnails could still take a while to load, and the nice things with sliding panes is the fact that the hidden data slides in quickly and smoothly preferbly without a loading delay.

So I was wondering from a performance and good practice point of view which option is best, this is what I can think of for now, open to suggestions.

1, call each set of images via JSON (its supposed to be fast?)

2,load all the possible images into a json file and pull in the details that way - although browser will still have to load image. Plus sometimes there might be 4 images, other times there could be upto 1000!

3, Load 10 images via php into a Json or other file, and load all 10 images into the browser hiding the 8 which are not on show, and always showing the middle two. Problem here is that each time someone clicks, the file has to reload the first and last images, which still takes up time, although i suppose the middle images will have all been cached via the browser by now though. But still there is a loading time.

4, Is it possible to have a json image with all the image details (regardless of numbers) and use no 3 above to load 10 of those images, is it possible to use ajax to only read 10 lines and keep a pointer of the last one it read, so the json file can be loaded fast, short refresh and images either side are cached via the browser!!

Hope thats clear, any suggestions on how you would handle this?

Comment: JSON is a text based transfer format, I don't think it'll provide any benefit for preloading images?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking more of it holding the image url, which I can then load via ajax, instead of requesting via php each time, just a quicker way to 'get' the info maybe?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To preload an image from Javascript, you don't need to do anything that sounds like AJAX or JSON. All you need is this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://example.com/new/image.jpg";
```

The browser will quite happily load the image in the background, even though it's not displayed anywhere. Then, when you update the `src` field of another (displayed) image tag, the browser will immediately show the part of the image it's already loaded (hopefully all of it).

Answer (score 1):

Fetching JSON Via Ajax will just slow you down.

You're better off using inline JSON and generated Javascript.

```
 <?php 
       $images = array( "foo.jpg","bar.jpg" ); 
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function($){
       var images = ( <?php echo json_encode($images); ?> ); 
       /* Creating A Hidden box to preload the images into */
       var imgbox = document.createElement("div"); 
       $(imgbox).css({display: 'none'});
       /* Possible Alternative trick */
       /* $(imgbox).css({height:1px; width: 1px; overflow: hidden;}); */
       $('body').append(imgbox);

       $.each( images , function( ind, item ) 
       {
          #Injecting images into the bottom hidden div. 
          var img = document.createElement("img"); 
          $(img).src("/some/prefix/" + item ); 
          $(imgbox).append(img);
       });
    }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you want to **concurrently** preload a larger number of resources, a little ajax can solve the problem for you.  Just make sure the caching headers are such that the browser will use the resources on the next request.  In the following example, I load up to four resources concurrently.

```
<script>
var urls = [
  "a.png",
  "b.png",
  "c.png",
  "d.png",
  "e.png",
  "f.png"
];

var currentStep = 0;
function loadResources()
{
  if(currentStep<urls.length){
  var url = urls[currentStep];
  var req = GetXmlHttpObject();
  update('loading ' + url);
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.onreadystatechange = getUpdateState(req, url);
  req.send(null);
} else {
  window.location = 'done.htm';
}
}

function getUpdateState(req, url) {
  return function() {
    var state = req.readyState;
    if (state != 4) { return; }
    req = null;
    setTimeout('loadResources()', 0);
  }
}
</script>

<!-- This will queue up to four concurrent requests.  Modern browsers will request up to eight images at time  -->
<body onload="javascript: loadResources(); loadResources(); loadResources(); loadResources();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use text and replace the text with a picture code (works in php really nice with ajax up to 500 pictures and more)?