# Error printing multiple images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image-processing

Developed a system where the user can index and query images.

It can also print these images. But when he registers, for example, over 100 images and try to print processing in the absurd fical browser, reaching up to lock the PC.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I could print these images without using the code below, thus avoiding catching and high processing PC?

```
<?php
$cpf = $_GET['cpf']; //valor_cpf_rg_cnpj
$data = $_GET['data'];

require_once '../class/cliente.class.php';

$cliente = new Cliente();
$imagens = $cliente->ObterImagensPorCpf($cpf, $data);

foreach ($imagens as $imagem) {
    ?>
    <img id="teste" src='../<?php echo $imagem['diretorio'] . $imagem['nome_imagem']; ?>' style="width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <?php
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>SIPI - Sistema de Indexação e Pesquisa de Imagem</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.print();"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: loading 100+ images will require longer loading time. Check this, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013412/how-to-load-the-body-of-html-after-loading-all-images

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested link did not help...