# jQuery, remove flicker when changing background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a flicker in Chrome, and FF although its much less in FF.
The script scrolls through 20 background jpg's according to horizontal mouse position.
This kind of works but very flickerish.

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
var xSlider = $("#third"); //cache
var loopvar = 10; //set start img to 10
xSlider.css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/' + loopvar + '.jpg)'}); 
document.onmousemove = function(e){
        var mouseposimg = Math.floor(e.pageX / Math.floor($(window).width() / 20) + 1);
        if (mouseposimg > 20) { mouseposimg = 21; } //if outside browser
        if (mouseposimg < 0) { mouseposimg = 1; }

        if(loopvar != mouseposimg) { 
            xSlider.css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/' + mouseposimg + '.jpg)'}); 
            loopvar = mouseposimg; 
        }


};
```

});

**CSS**

```
#third{
background: no-repeat 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div id="third">
</div>
```

Forgot to mention I do preload with this

```
(function(d){var h=[];d.loadImages=function(a,e){"string"==typeof a&&(a=[a]);for(var f=a.length,g=0,b=0;b<f;b++){var c=document.createElement("img");c.onload=function(){g++;g==f&&d.isFunction(e)&&e()};c.src=a[b];h.push(c)}}})(jQuery);
```

$.loadImages(['1.jpg', '2.jpg', etc etc etc])

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to smooth this out? I am researching and trying to sort this out. I have preloaded and tested, but I am getting a flicker when the css updates the image.

Comment: I ended up putting all the images in 1 big image and change the offset with css

Answer (score 6):

The flicker is probably due to the image loading.  You can just preload all of the images to work to prevent this:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 21; x++) {
    (new Image).src = 'images/' + x + '.jpg';
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention I do preload
see above

Comment: @OlivierLangelaar try my method above, I came accross many preloading techniques that don't work well before building my own. It might well be that your preloading method isn't working as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks tried yours and some others, still some flicker though
Think the problem lies in the fact that every pixel the mouse moves the background gets set. which is a lot of times on a 1000px screen

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to preload the images first. Get the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin and try the following:

```
function preload(sources, callback) {
    if(sources.length) {
        var preloaderDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>').prependTo(document.body);

        $.each(sources, function(i,source) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", source).appendTo(preloaderDiv);

            if(i == (sources.length-1)) {
                $(preloaderDiv).imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                    if(callback) callback();
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        if(callback) callback();
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    var xSlider = $("#third"); //cache
    var loopvar = 10; //set start img to 10

    var filesToPreload = [];
    for(var x = 1; x <= 21; x++) filesToPreload.push('images/' + x + '.jpg');

    preload(filesToPreload, function() {
        xSlider.css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/' + loopvar + '.jpg)'}); 

        document.onmousemove = function(e){
            var mouseposimg = Math.floor(e.pageX / Math.floor($(window).width() / 20) + 1);
            if (mouseposimg > 20) { mouseposimg = 21; } //if outside browser
            if (mouseposimg < 0) { mouseposimg = 1; }

            if(loopvar != mouseposimg) { 
                xSlider.css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/' + mouseposimg + '.jpg)'}); 
                loopvar = mouseposimg; 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See also: [The definitive best way to preload images using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901677/the-definitive-best-way-to-preload-images-using-javascript-jquery/)