# How to check image file from other site is visible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I use image file from other site.

```
<img src="//othersite.url/xxx.jpg">
```

But it's often unvisible.
Because Http status is 404 ,301, etc.

How can I check the image can be visible?

Comment: Your question is unclear: Do you want to do this *client-side* (JavaScript, jQuery, HTML, CSS), or *server-side* (PHP)?

Comment: "other" site means `http://` doing `//` only checks what's on "your" server.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: No, because it's a `//`, not just a `/`, it's a [*protocol-relative URL*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *I stand corrected* ;-)

Comment: use a javscript image preloader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901677/the-definitive-best-way-to-preload-images-using-javascript-jquery/901699#901699

Comment: get_headers has problem.
301,302 can be visible or unvisible.
200 can be unvisible...

Comment: My database has many image url.
I want to output only visible image url.
So if image is unvisible, I want to add unvisible_flg on database.
Anyway client-side or server-side.

Comment: Google HTML/CSS Style Guide Recommended "//example.com/" Not recommended "http://example.com/".

Answer (score 0):

In php you can check it if file exist ..

```
<?php
$imageurl=//othersite.url/xxx.jpg;
if(file_exists($imageurl)
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onload` and `onerror` event handlers.

```
<img src="//othersite.url/xxx.jpg" onerror="alert('error')"  onload="alert('image loaded')" >
```